# whats the simplest way to write a palindrome string using a while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop

I've searched about everywhere but I just can't find anything very concrete. I've been working on this code for awhile now but it keeps stumping me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(palindrome("word"));
}

public static boolean palindrome(String myPString) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    String word = in.nextLine();
    String reverse = "";
    int startIndex = 0;
    int str = word.length() -1;

    while(str >= 0) {
        reverse = reverse + word.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is`i`?  Where does `str` get decremented?

Comment: Looks like you're on track to reverse a word, not create, or check a palindrome... Unclear what output you're expecting

Comment: Why are you even using a Scanner? You're taking a string as a parameter

Comment: *"I've searched about everywhere but I just cant find any thing very concrete I've been working at this code for awhile but it keeps stumping me."* - I think that you are doing this the wrong way.  You don't learn to program by searching for solutions.  That like looking up the answers in the back of a maths text book.  You learn to program by actually programming.  My advice: stop googling, stop asking us for help, and keep working on it.

Comment: Yeah, don't try to copy code -- start from scratch.  First just write "pseudocode" -- lines in English that explain what you do at each step (or draw a flow chart).  Then translate those lines into your target language.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to accomplish this using a `while` loop.
Thinking about simplicity, you can imagine how could you do this if you had a set of plastic separated character in a table in front of you.
Probably you'll think about get the second character and move it to the begin, then get the third and move to begin, and so on until reach the last one, right?

```
0123    1023    2103    3210
WORD -> OWRD -> ROWD -> DROW
```

So, you'll just need two code:

```
init a variable i with 1 (the first moved character)
while the value of i is smaller than total string size do
    replace the string with 
       char at i plus
       substring from 0 to i plus
       substring from i+1 to end
    increment i
print the string
```

The process should be:

```
o + w + rd
r + ow + d
d + row + 

drow
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is an piece of code I write a while back that uses almost the same process. Hope it helps!

```
    String original;
    String reverse = "";

    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    original = input.nextLine();
    for(int x = original.length(); x > 0; x--)
    {
        reverse += original.charAt(x - 1);
    }

    System.out.println("The reversed string is " +reverse);
```